# Find out if a TFS work item is a successor in C#

Tags: c#, tfs, workitem

I have an application that finds changesets on a workitem and its related workitems changesets. My Method takes a list of workitem ids. I first want to check if the workitem id is a successor before iterating through the list. How would I do this?

```
foreach (string workItemId in _workItemIds)
      WorkItem workItemSuccessor = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(int.Parse(workItemId));
      object workItemType = workItemSuccessor.Fields["?"].Value;
```

what property finds out if a workitem is a successor?

I cant seem to find any documentation online on how I would determine this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the work item links (either [WorkItemLinks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.workitemlinks(v=vs.120).aspx) or [Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.links(v=vs.120).aspx)) and look for predecesor/successor links, then check on which side of the links this work item is.

The link type [reference name for this link type is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293527.aspx): `System.LinkTypes.Dependency`.

Comment: In debug for each link I do not find a property that has any info of predecessor/successor links

Comment: Nevermind, it is a property called LinkTypeEnd. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If this fixed your problem, please mark the answer as such. Use the checkmark in front of the score.